# CakePHP find screwed up

Tags: cakephp

I have a simple database table which looks like this: http://www.xup.in/dl,17431410/screwed.jpg/ Now I want the data using `$this->find('all')` in the ItemModel which looks like:

```
public function getList() {
        $data = $this->find('all');
        pr($data);
        exit;
    }
```

The output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Champion] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => A
                    [key] => ahri
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Champion] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => A
                    [key] => akali
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Champion] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => A
                    [key] => alistar
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Champion] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [name] => A
                    [key] => amumu
                )

        )
)
```

I have absolutely no idea why the name is cut at the first letter.

Comment: you should provide the database scheme

Comment: Ah sorry, here it is: http://www.xup.in/dl,16357143/schema.jpg/

Answer (score 0):

schema looks good to me.
did you clear the cache? the old scheme that is cached in /tmp/cache/persistent might still have something else stored.
maybe a tinyint, or char 1 etc.

Comment: Hm, no. I cleared the cache and deleted all files and this bug still remains. :/

Comment: you probably have some afterFind callback running somewhere - in a model or maybe a behavior?